# jQuery selectable and disable inputs in selected table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I a little bit new on jQuery and trying for several hours and days to get something simple working. I'm using a table with in each cell a input field. I've implemented the selectable option of jQuery to select multiple rows and columns.

What I want is that After the selection is done the input in the selected cells must be disabled.

With the following code all the inputs in the table will be disabled, not only the selected ones.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Display as grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
  </style>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
      stop: function (event, ui) 
      {
        $(".ui-selected", this).each(function()
        {
          var element = $("#selectable tr td");
          var index = element.index(this);

          if (index > -1)
          {
            element.find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', true);          
          }
        });
      },
      unselected: function (event, ui) 
      {
        //$(ui.unselected).removeClass('selectedfilter');
      }
    });                
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="selectable">
 <tr>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value1" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value2" value="2"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value3" value="3"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value4" value="4"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value1" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value2" value="2"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value3" value="3"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value4" value="4"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value1" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value2" value="2"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value3" value="3"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value4" value="4"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value1" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value2" value="2"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value3" value="3"/></td>
   <td class="ui-state-default"><input type="text" id="value4" value="4"/></td>
 </tr>
</table>


<div id="output"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully someone here can help me.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript to :

```
$(function() {
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
  stop: function (event, ui) 
  {
      $("td.ui-selected input").prop('disabled', true);
  },
  unselected: function (event, ui) 
  {          
    $(ui.unselected).removeClass('selectedfilter');
  }
 });                
});
```

check the live sample in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5Eg/)

Comment: Nice, thanks for helping me.

The only remaining thing now is about scrollen. When the page isn't scrolled, the selection is working fine. When the page is scrolled, the selection box is starting from the beginning of the page and looks it doesn't handled the offset since the scrolling event.